# using jquery .find() to get children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="items">
   <div class="item">
     <div class="item_box" id="id_1">
       <div class="one" id="one"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">
     <div class="item_box" id="id_2">
       <div class="one" id="two"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">
     <div class="item_box" id="id_3">
       <div class="one" id="three"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Basically, I want to be able to loop through and get the id value in the item_box class.

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
$('#items').find(/[id_]/).each(
      function(){
         alert($(this).attr('id'));
      });
```

This doesn't work though... I've tried using .children, however that won't go as deep as these are nested.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason yours didn't work was that you needed to use the "attribute starts with" selector: `$('#items').find("[id^=id_]")` or: `$('#items [id^=id_]')`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#items').find('.item_box').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Here's your code, modified to search for children of `#items` which have an id that starts with `id_`

```
$('#items *[id^=id_]').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Search by Class 'item_box'
2. iterate them to collect ids

​

```
$(function(){

    var child = $('#items').find('div.item_box');

    var idArray = new Array();

    if(child.length){

        $.each(child,function(i,entry){

            idArray.push($(this).attr('id'));

        });

    }

    console.log(idArray);

});​
```

Fiddle Assistance : http://jsfiddle.net/FFp4B/