# Get Child inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

So guys, I have some HTML like this:

```
<ul id="view-id54795_breadcrumbs" class="xbreadcrumbs">
    <li id="view-id54795_bcitem0" class="ncurrent">All XYZ</li>
    <li id="view-id54795_bcitem1" class="current">ABC</li>
</ul>
```

I need the text in the children, so I started with simple functions like:

```
console.log($('#'+t.view.id+'_breadcrumbs').childNodes);
//console.log($('#'+t.view.id+'_breadcrumbs').getChildren());
```

Both of which didnt work. I also tried the function below

```
$(function(){
    var child = $('#'+t.view.id+'_breadcrumbs').find('li.t.view.id_');
    console.log(child.innerHTML);
    var idArray = new Array();

    if(child.length) {                              
        $.each(child,function(i,entry) {                                
            idArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    }

    console.log(idArray);                               
});
```

PS.

The function code above has been taken from the reference post [using jquery .find() to get children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098709/using-jquery-find-to-get-children).
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you format your code properly and consistently, it's easier to read.

Comment: You wanna get the li children, is it?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbhardwa/6r12phgx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var ul = $('#'+t.view.id+'_breadcrumbs');
var children = ul.find('li[id^="' + t.view.id + '"]');

var childText = [];

for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    childText.push(children[i].innerHTML);
}
```

The jQuery find uses the 'startsWith' selector, so any `li` whose id begins with `t.view.id` will be returned.

The childText should be filled with each `li` text.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljn0ym6e/4/)

Comment: reason for adding this as answer :This is a more comprehensive version as it taken in account the unique view id . Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

What about this selector instead?

```
$('.xbreadcrumbs li')
```

A more complete version would be:

```
$(function(){ 
    var children = $('.xbreadcrumbs li');
    children.each(function(i,v)
    {
       console.log($(v).text()); 
     });                         
});
```

Comment: @w00d I am guessing the breadcrumbs may change based on a view, hence the odd Id given to the UL. Going with the selector you proposed may not be available. But, without more details we can't be certain. While it will work, it does have a higher potential to break. When working with breadcrumbs there's usually one per page. And mine will end up returning too much data. Without the proper context this is used in we really can't tell.

Comment: works like a breeze . Wish I had enough credits to upvote . Thanks @cgatian . PS.Yep view ID are dynamic and change with each refresh .

Comment: I personally prefer using classes rather than doing string concatenation for unique ids. If `xbreadcrumbs` is used for other things as well then I'd prefer adding another class for this specific use

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementById('view-id54795_breadcrumbs');
list.forEach(function(element) {
console.log(element.innerHTML);
});
```

note: forEach is only available in ECMAScript 5 implemtation, sorry for vanilla JS, i don't know jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Just select your ul and do a .find() passing the li tag selector

```
$(function(){
var children = $('#view-id54795_breadcrumbs').find('li');

var idArray = new Array();

if(children.length) {                              
    $.each(child,function(i,entry) {    

        console.log($(this).html());

        idArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}

console.log(idArray);
```

});